# CSS unable to change div position, this is causing clipping

Tags: html, css, wordpress, video, youtube

When you go and play a video on our site the youtube video container goes down and a part of the video is cut from the top.

[image]

See http://laughpot.com/a-terryfying-world-record-on-a-bike-must-watch/

I recently added few CSS to make the video description look nicer and this is happening since I did that.

I even removed my custom CSS but the video is still cutting.

Can anyone please inspect the video div using Chrome developer tools and figure it out which CSS class or rule is causing this issue? I tried to find it but I got no success.

I will be very thankful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this set this css on

1.) iframe {height:473px;} and

2.) set display:none for class yesp-title

output get like this

[image: Output]

Comment: do you know how can I add a custom jQuery delay on top of a youtube video to prompt user to share video on facebook before playing? Like it is happening here, http://roflpot.tv/videos/most-shocking-airplane-accident-caught-on-tape/

Answer (score 1):

There is a top that is causing this problem on the element itself the video class="video-stream html5-main-video" within the class="html5-video-container"

top: 101.25px;

Answer (score 0):

To resolve this issue, more elegantly you can use fitvid jQuery library

http://fitvidsjs.com/

WP plugin is also available for fitvids.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/fitvids-for-wordpress/